# OneLogin API User Resource Status

Tags: rest, onelogin

I am working on a PowerShell module that performs administrative functions against the OneLogin API. According to the documentation [here](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/users/user-resource), users have status values of 1-5. However, I am seeing status values outside of that range, with at least 1 user returning a value of 8. I'm currently using an enum to replace this value with a readable string, and this breaks the code.

Can anyone from OneLogin clarify the status values? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs on status are incomplete. Here's the complete list (and I'll see about getting the docs updated)

- STATUS_UNACTIVATED              = 0
- STATUS_ACTIVE                   = 1
- STATUS_SUSPENDED                = 2
- STATUS_LOCKED                   = 3
- STATUS_PASSWORD_EXPIRED         = 4
- STATUS_AWAITING_PASSWORD_RESET  = 5
- STATUS_PENDING                  = 6
- STATUS_PENDING_PASSWORD         = 7
- STATUS_SECURITY_QUESTIONS_REQUIRED = 8

Comment: Thanks for this! I'll update my project to allow for these values.

Comment: Looks like this one may be out of date as well:
https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/events/event-resource
I'm getting at least one event of type 213 which is not listed in the event types table. Thanks!

Comment: I found that 213 represents "Actor_user uploaded profile picture," and 214 is "Actor_user removed profile picture." I'm guessing there are others that might be missing from the table as well.